How to have two accounts with a Windows 11 system and use fingerprint to sign into both?
I have two user accounts on a Windows 11 system. I can setup fingerprint sign-in for both accounts by using different fingers. However this only works for a limited time before “Windows Hello” stops offering fingerprint as an option.
I have also tried only doing it on one of the accounts and not the other, but again it stops working after a few sign-in's. And since I've been unlucky enough to have a complete system failure on my first computer (HP), I have also been able to attempt this on a replacement ASUS machine with the same results.

Not sure it has to do with two different accounts: apparently a known issue on a single account -- see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/my-fingerprint-login-suddenly-stopped-working-how/3d5d8cc5-79e0-4cea-8ecf-4f46cbec4ec2 and https://community.frame.work/t/solved-windows-hello-fingerprint-sensor-no-longer-working/16515/6, for example, with fixes (e.g., drivers, Group Policy, etc.)
